# VB.NET Multiple Nested JSON Listed By Lowest First

Tags: json, vb.net

**My JSON**

```
    {
        "items": {
            "averageItemLevel": 564,
            "averageItemLevelEquipped": 564,
            "head": {
                "id": 99161,
                "stats": [
                    {
                        "stat": 32,
                        "amount": 651,
                        "reforgedAmount": -434
                    },
                    {
                        "stat": 5,
                        "amount": 2001
                    },
                    {
                        "stat": 36,
                        "amount": 1544
                    },
                    {
                        "stat": 7,
                        "amount": 3362
                    },
                    {
                        "stat": 49,
                        "amount": 434,
                        "reforged": true
                    }
                ],
                "armor": 2244
            }


}
}
```

**Current code**

```
Dim stat0 = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString())
            Select Case stat0
                Case 1
                    stat0lbl.Text = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() + " Health")
                Case 2
                    stat0lbl.Text = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() + " Mana")
                Case 3
                    stat0lbl.Text = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() + " Agility")
                Case 4
                    stat0lbl.Text = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() + " Strength")
                Case 5
                    stat0lbl.Text = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() + " Intellect")
                Case 6
                    stat0lbl.Text = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() + " Spirit")
                Case 7
                    stat0lbl.Text = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() + " Stamina")

    And So on....
End Select
```

This Would Produce A Label Text That Says

```
32 Critical Strike
```

However what i would really like to do is display all the stats so it would look like

```
+3362 Stamina
+2001 Intellect
+651 Critical Strike
+1544 Haste
+434 Mastery (Reforged From Critical Strike)
```

All In One Multiline Field If Possible So I Dont Have To Define Every Stat

I Imagine for the reforge it would be an `If`

I'm not sure how to make it display without using individual labels and I would much prefer a better way if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

What you could do in your case, set up a `RootClass` that will model the structure of your JSON. Use the Free [Newtonsoft JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json) Library to serialize/deserialize.

**Like so:**

```
Public Class Stat
    Public Property stat() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_stat
        End Get
        Set
            m_stat = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_stat As Integer
    Public Property amount() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_amount
        End Get
        Set
            m_amount = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_amount As Integer
    Public Property reforgedAmount() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_reforgedAmount
        End Get
        Set
            m_reforgedAmount = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_reforgedAmount As Integer
    Public Property reforged() As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
        Get
            Return m_reforged
        End Get
        Set
            m_reforged = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_reforged As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
End Class

Public Class Head
    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set
            m_id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_id As Integer
    Public Property stats() As List(Of Stat)
        Get
            Return m_stats
        End Get
        Set
            m_stats = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_stats As List(Of Stat)
    Public Property armor() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_armor
        End Get
        Set
            m_armor = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_armor As Integer
End Class

Public Class Items
    Public Property averageItemLevel() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_averageItemLevel
        End Get
        Set
            m_averageItemLevel = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_averageItemLevel As Integer
    Public Property averageItemLevelEquipped() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_averageItemLevelEquipped
        End Get
        Set
            m_averageItemLevelEquipped = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_averageItemLevelEquipped As Integer
    Public Property head() As Head
        Get
            Return m_head
        End Get
        Set
            m_head = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_head As Head
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property items() As Items
        Get
            Return m_items
        End Get
        Set
            m_items = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_items As Items
End Class
```

Then you can `Deserialize` your Data and create a List of Objects that will expand dynamically.

**For example**

```
Dim parsed As String = "yourJsonWillbeHere"
Dim deserialized As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(parsed.ToString())
```

---

**Update #2**

Here is a full working example I created in VB.NET, I hope this helps you.

**NOTE:** Remember to download Newtonsoft Json.Net library and add the reference to the DLL you download. Of this example will not work, Notice i'm `Imports Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
Option Explicit On

Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim jsonData As String = "{""items"":{""averageItemLevel"":564,""averageItemLevelEquipped"":564,""head"":{""id"":99161,""stats"":[{""stat"":32,""amount"":651,""reforgedAmount"":-434},{""stat"":5,""amount"":2001},{""stat"":36,""amount"":1544},{""stat"":7,""amount"":3362},{""stat"":49,""amount"":434,""reforged"":true}],""armor"":2244}}}"

        Dim deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(jsonData.ToString())

        Console.WriteLine("Head Stats: ")

        For Each item In deserialized.items.head.stats
            Console.WriteLine("Amount: " + item.amount.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine("Reforged: " + item.reforged.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine("Reforged Amount: " + item.reforgedAmount.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine("Stat: " + item.stat.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine("---------")
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Stat
    Public Property stat() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_stat
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_stat = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_stat As Integer
    Public Property amount() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_amount
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_amount = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_amount As Integer
    Public Property reforgedAmount() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_reforgedAmount
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_reforgedAmount = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_reforgedAmount As Integer
    Public Property reforged() As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
        Get
            Return m_reforged
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Nullable(Of Boolean))
            m_reforged = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_reforged As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
End Class

Public Class Head
    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_id As Integer
    Public Property stats() As List(Of Stat)
        Get
            Return m_stats
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Stat))
            m_stats = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_stats As List(Of Stat)
    Public Property armor() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_armor
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_armor = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_armor As Integer
End Class

Public Class Items
    Public Property averageItemLevel() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_averageItemLevel
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_averageItemLevel = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_averageItemLevel As Integer
    Public Property averageItemLevelEquipped() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_averageItemLevelEquipped
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_averageItemLevelEquipped = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_averageItemLevelEquipped As Integer
    Public Property head() As Head
        Get
            Return m_head
        End Get
        Set(value As Head)
            m_head = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_head As Head
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property items() As Items
        Get
            Return m_items
        End Get
        Set(value As Items)
            m_items = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_items As Items
End Class
```

Comment: i think you may have missuderstood i dont wish to do `txtTextbox.Text += jResults("items")...` for every stat id like to pull them all and display them if possible

Comment: the issue is some times there can be 3 stats and the next may have 7 im looking for a way to pull the whole stat group from json and output them easily

Comment: No offense, look into C#! I was very into VB.NET and to be honest, the change to C# is worth it. ;)

Comment: i think i will make the switch after this project how do i convert your C# To VB.net?

Comment: can i set the head object to itemtypelbl.Text as on each hover it is a differant item EG head, neck, shoulder, etc... and the itemtypelbl.Text defines it

Comment: and my rootclass being my namespace?

Comment: This is becoming too long for comments, if you wish we can move to chat here on SO.

Comment: yeah sure just tell me where

Comment: i cant seem to find you in the chat

Comment: @ids I wont be able to join at the moment. Check my updated answer in a minute, I will try to give you a better insight on whats happening.

Comment: this helped a little i think i converted the console to labels as it kept throwing an exception on the console, i'm now tinkering with it to try and get it to use a url rather than a user inputted string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48713/discussion-between-ids-and-dayan)